# Image will not take specified width?

Tags: html, image

I am using firefox which from my research seems to be part of the problem. I specify in the `<img>` tag that the width should be 360 and the height 215 yet it makes the width 382 and the height 215. I checked and this maintains the original ratio which I am trying to break in my resize. Why does it do this and how do I make it stop? If I want to I should be able to make it have a height of 124358907 and a width of 1.

```
<img src="myfile.png" height="215" width="360" />
```

Then when I click on image properties it says that the width is 382 and based on how it looks compared to other images which resized correctly I can confirm that it is a tad too wide.

Firefox version 17.0.1

Comment: What about css rules on the `img`?

Comment: Please post HTML and CSS code that demonstrate the issue, and identify the Firefox version(s) tested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seriously dude? Check this out, you can resize your `img` tag, you are probably doing something wrong at your side

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/R2AbX/)

CSS

```
img {
    height: 15px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: I'm doing this for a school project and I know HTML, CSS, JS, and PHP but I have to use a WYSIWYG editor because my group mates are technologically illiterate. I would imagine that there is something in the CSS of the WYSIWYG that is throwing me off.

Comment: @ChapmIndustries I don't know cuz am using notepad++, example is right in front of you, ignore using `height, width` attributes, go for CSS

Comment: I switched to `style="height:215px; width:360;"` and it's good now.

Comment: @ChapmIndustries I told ya...CSS is goooood, and btw try ignoring inline styles, will be tough for you to maintain, use, a stylesheet instead, if not than make a class inside a style tag and place it in between the document head element

Comment: @ChapmIndustries, in CSS, `width:360` is incorrect and is ignored by conforming browsers; a unit (`px`) is required.

Answer (score 1):

Just curious, is it in the WYSIWYG editor that the image isn't displaying correctly or is it actually in the browser? I remember having issues with that in older versions of Dreamweaver, certain things would display strangely in Dreamweaver's display, but when you actually open  the HTML file in a browser, everything displays as it should. Same with the old Microsoft Front Page. I just use Sublime Text or Notepad++ now...

Comment: This sounds like the most probable explanation. @ChapmIndustries should check this out by opening the page in a browser (when the original code is used) against what he sees in the authoring program.